powerBI DENEB Pie chart
iam trying to create a pie chart with an extra arc to show the sub division with in the pie. the main problem is that the pies are not stacked one after one, they are starting from 0 for for both the pies
If you see the first 10 % is correct but the fullifilled is is also starting from 0 instead it stack after the open % in the pie chart( in have increased the open % radius to show you what is happening
vega lite code https://vega.github.io/editor/#/edited
image-  [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/Ujsyz0ED.png

it's still correct , what you looking for could be achived using reverse , the second percentage must be 2 values an empty 98% and a filled with red 2%

@YasserCHENIK, actually i did not get your point. in vega editor if you see the pies are stacked properly one after other but  while using it in powerbi with Dataset command and measures. the pies are stacked one upon one as shown in the image(image is from powerbi deneb visual)

if you want to show 1% on the end and not on the begining , create a "fake" invisible 99% to push the 1% to the end , you want pre coded solutions . you can't expect insane flexibility
